# How to submit data from an html page forcing the browser keeps the page unchanged

Tags: html

First let me set the situation.
I am writing a simple client html page and a simple server side program.
In detail, the page has a submit button to POST some data to the server program.
The problem is that any time I test the page to push the submit button ,the browser displays the new page which displays only the return message my server program returned.
How can I modify the html or the server side program so that the browser keeps the page unchanged before after the submit button is pushed.
I know an easiest way ; letting the sever program returns the same string as the client html page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular form submission, your page will be whatever the server sends back.  The form's action might be the same page, and then your server-side code can read the value of any input fields, and set the values in the response back to what they were in the request.  This should result in the page looking the same as it did before the submit button was pressed.  However, the page has "changed" in the sense that it was reloaded.

Alternatively, your form can make an Ajax request, which means that you'd need to use Javascript to intercept and stop the form submission, and then use additional coding to send the Ajax request, and then receive and process the response.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably a postback:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback

Comment: @GoingTham, thank you very much for the answer. Although my area is not ASP, knowing the term,I can ask people how to do postback with my web languages.

Comment: @CoingTham,thank you very much .Knowing the term, I can ask people how to do postback ,not with ASP.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.) AJAX

You could use JavaScript and AJAX to POST the data.

#### 2.) IFrame (not recommended)

You could also create a hidden IFrame and set the `target` attribute of the form to it.

Comment: ,thank you very much.I will check the terms,IFrame and setting the target attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do doesn't seem to be very clear.

If you want to submit your POST data without loading a new web page, you can use Ajax. It may be simple to do it in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), and even simpler if you [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form data.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $.post('your-post-url',$(this).serialize(),function(data) {
    alert('Data posted!');
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: ,thank you very much,I'll check the terms,jQuery and serialize.